# How to select rows with same identifier and only one value in a second column in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table is:

```
sid  status   
----|-------|
 18 | 1     | 
 23 | 3     | 
 23 | 3     | 
 44 | 3     | 
 44 | 1     | 
 44 | 3     |
```

I need to select sid rows where status is **only** "3":

The result will be:

```
sid  status   
----|-------|
 23 | 3     | 
 23 | 3     |
```

How can I do this in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get all rows for which a corresponding row with the same `sid` but a different `status` does not exist:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE status = 3
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM MyTable AS T2
                  WHERE T2.sid = MyTable.sid
                    AND T2.status != 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `not exists` subquery to filter out rows for which another row exists with the same `sid` and `status = 3`:

```
select  sid
,       status
from    YourTable yt1
where   not exists  
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.sid = yt2.sid
                and yt2.status <> 3
        )
```